# Load object from file design

Tags: c++

What is the best design for loading an object from a file? There are lots of possibilities, some of which are shown below.

```
class object
{
public:
    object(const std::string& filename);
};

class object
{
public:
    object();
    void load_from_file(const std::string& filename);
};

class object
{
public:
    static object load_from_file(const std::string& filename);

    object(object&& an_object);
};

class object
{
public:
    std::unique_ptr<object> load_from_file(const std::string& filename);
};

class object_loader
{
public:
    std::unique_ptr<object> load_object_from_file(const std::string& filename);
};
```

and the list goes on...

Edit:

The design I went with was this:

```
class object
{
public:
    object();
};

class object_loader
{
public:
    void load_from_stream(object& an_object, std::istream& input_stream);
};
```

Comment: Frankly, you shouldn't be passing a filename at all.  You should be passing an `istream` reference.  An class doesn't need to know *where* the bytes are coming from; it just needs a way to read the bytes and make sense of them.

Comment: Good idea. Still, which design is the best (just imagine const std::string& filename is replaced with std::istream& input_stream)?

Comment: @cHao: My opinion on that subject oscillates wildly over time. I don't disagree with you in principle, but sometimes it's nice to just have all that file nonsense abstracted away from the call site and in certain applications it does make sense.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: I guess if you know for certain that these objects will only ever come from a file, and a file will contain exactly one, it might make sense to simply pass a filename.  But it seems to me that you could easily make a template function to load an object specifically from a file -- which would abstract away the file stuff without sacrificing the ability to unserialize an object from other sources.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would prefer 'class object_loader' which separates the IO loader from the container, allowing future implementation of different loaders (from txt, binary, xml ... file) without modifying original data container. Better testing possible. Also possible to remove IO from app, if no IO allowed (like embedded devices, etc).

Comment: I would upvote the answer, but I don't have enough reputation yet, so thanks!

Comment: Don't worry, I can upvote it :D

Answer (score 2):

> What is the best design for loading an object from a file?

The best design usually is along these lines:

```
class object { public: object(); /* ... */ }; // object is default constructible

std::istream& operator >> (std::istream& in, object& o);
```

client code:

```
// from file:
std::ifstream fin(path);
object o;
fin >> o;
// from serialized string:
std::string contents = ".....";
std::istrigstream ssin(contents);
ssin >> o;
```

Edit:

Transactional implementation:

```
std::istream& operator >> (std::istream& in, object& o)
{
    int i; std::string word; // example data required by object instance
    if (in >> i >> word)
    { // read was successful for all data
        o.set_index(i);
        o.set_word(word);
    }
    return in;
}

// client code:
if(ssin >> o)
{ // read was successful
    // use o here
} else {
    // o is still as default-constructed
}
```

This approach will work the same also if the stream throws exceptions on errors.

Comment: Nice, I didn't think of that. What if it doesn't make sense for the object to be default constructed, though? Would object(std::istream& input_stream) be the better choice?

Comment: good pattern, but you won't be able to load the object from different file types (if in future required support to load from txt, xml,...)

Comment: @Cole, it does make more sense, if you can guarantee that the object in the stream is correctly serialized (otherwise you end up with `o` in an invalid state).

Comment: @dousin Very true. I am now leaning towards using an object_loader that takes istream references. I have two more questions, though. 1) Do you think I should return unique_ptr<object> from loading functions or object (calling the move constructor)? 2) Should the loading functions be static?

Comment: @utnapistim True. I guess there's no avoiding invalid object states regardless of whether a default constructor is used.

Comment: @utnapistim Thanks for your helpful answer and comments. I accepted dousin's answer simply because it allows for loading objects from multiple formats.

Comment: @Cole, invalid object states can be avoided easily with a transactional i/o implementation (transactional here means "only alter the state of `o` if all data was read successfully).

Comment: @cole: sorry, I am not familiar with c++11 syntax. If the object should go out of scope, you will probably want to use something different than unique_ptr. Ad 2) function can also be a non-static - consider an opened db connection loader in 'class object_db_loader', so depends on your needs